# How to show relationship between GMM and 2SLS estimators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working through Exercise 13.21 of [Hansen's Econometrics](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf) (page 438). I expanded $Z = \begin{bmatrix} Z_1 & Z_2\end{bmatrix}$ and got

$$
\overline{\beta} = \Big(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Z_1}(\mathbf{Z_1}'\mathbf{Z_1})^{-1}\mathbf{Z_1}'\mathbf{X}\lambda + \mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Z_2}(\mathbf{Z_2}'\mathbf{Z_2})^{-1}\mathbf{Z_2}'\mathbf{X}(1-\lambda)\Big)^{-1} \Big(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Z_1}(\mathbf{Z_1}'\mathbf{Z_1})^{-1}\mathbf{Z_1}'\mathbf{Y}\lambda + \mathbf{X}'\mathbf{Z_2}(\mathbf{Z_2}'\mathbf{Z_2})^{-1}\mathbf{Z_2}'\mathbf{Y}(1-\lambda)\Big)
$$

From the formulas for
$\widehat{\beta} = \mathbf{(X'Z_1(Z_1'Z_1)^{-1}Z_1'X)^{-1}X'Z_1(Z_1'Z_1)^{-1}Z_1'Y}$ and $    \widetilde{\beta} = \mathbf{(X'Z_2(Z_2'Z_2)^{-1}Z_2'X)^{-1}X'Z_2(Z_2'Z_2)^{-1}Z_2'Y}$, I can see that there should be some sort of relationship (they look the same at least), but I can't manipulate $\overline{\beta}$ into a function of the other two. Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Premultiply $\overline{\beta}$ by the denominator,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\lambda X^{\top}P_{1}X+\left(1-\lambda\right)X^{\top}P_{2}X\right)\overline{\beta}&=\lambda X^{\top}P_{1}Y+\left(1-\lambda\right)X^{\top}P_{2}Y\\
&=\lambda X^{\top}P_{1}X\widehat{\beta}+\left(1-\lambda\right)X^{\top}P_{2}X\widetilde{\beta}
\end{align}$$
Therefore $\overline{\beta}=W_{1}\widehat{\beta}+W_{2}\widetilde{\beta}$ with $W_{1}=\left(\lambda X^{\top}P_{1}X+\left(1-\lambda\right)X^{\top}P_{2}X\right)^{-1}\lambda X^{\top}P_{1}X$ and $W_{2}=\left(\lambda X^{\top}P_{1}X+\left(1-\lambda\right)X^{\top}P_{2}X\right)^{-1}\left(1-\lambda\right)X^{\top}P_{2}X$. You can verify that $W_{1}+W_{2}=I$ hence is a weighted average.